# calculate the numbers of occurrences in a csv file in scala spark-RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

suppose these are my CSV file:

```
11111;44444
22222;55555
11111;44444
33333;99999
11111;77777
22222;99999
```

I want to have the number of occurrences in the first column with different values of the second column.
Like this :

```
(11111,2)
(22222,2)
(33333,1)
```

i've tried:

```
object CountDestOcc {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("Word Count")
    .setMaster("local")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    //loading text file into textFile object .(RDD)
    val textFile = sc.textFile(args(0))

   val appsdest = textFile.flatMap (line => line.split(" ")).map(p=>(p,1)).reduceByKey(_+_).collect()
   appsdest.foreach(println)
   sc.stop()

  }
```

I get :

```
(22222;55555,1)
(22222;99999,1)
(11111;77777,1)
(11111;44444,2)
(33333;99999,1)
```

How I can only consolidate with the first key to having the expected result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would probably just count distinct values.

```
textFile.distinct() // remove all duplicate key;value pairs
    .map( line => line.split(";")(0) ) // extract the keys
    .map( k => (k,1) ) // convert to countable tuples
    .reduceByKey(_+_) // count keys
```

---

Stepwise, the following would happen

Assuming the input is:

```
11111;44444
22222;55555
11111;44444
33333;99999
11111;77777
22222;99999
```

1. `distinct()`

The input is turned into:

```
11111;44444
22222;55555
33333;99999
11111;77777
22222;99999
```

2. `.map( line => line.split(";")(0) )` and `.map( k=> (k,1) )` (or  `.map( line => (line.split(";")(0),1) )` in one map)

The input is turned into:

```
11111,1
22222,1
33333,1
11111,1
22222,1
```

3. `reduceByKey(_+_)`

Things are summarised to:

```
11111,2
22222,2
33333,1
```

Comment: Your explanation is wonderful,it's working now thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

you can add this to your code :

```
val appsdest = textFile.flatMap (line => line.split(" ")).
map(p=>(p,1)).reduceByKey(_+_). //your code
map(case(String, Int) => (String.split(";")(0),1)). //ditch the count to get distinctness
reduceByKey(_+_).collect()
```

this should work. I post this answer to help the OP with original code dev. the goal can be achieved in many other, far better methods.

Comment: I get an error : **value split is not a member of (String, Int)**